# requestAnimationFrame not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requestanimationframe, debouncing

I'm trying to implement debouncing in React on the `resize` event, using `requestAnimationFrame` and wrote the following simple CodePen:

https://codepen.io/robloche/pen/RmLjZV

But the behaviour is not consistent across Chrome (v75), Firefox (v67) and Edge (v42), although the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) states that it should be.

When I resize the window, quickly dragging the edge back and forth, here's what's displayed in the console:

[image: Resizing console output on Chrome] [image: Resizing console output on Firefox] [image: Resizing console output on Edge]

```
Chrome                      Firefox                    Edge
```

Only edge behaves as I expected.

Am I misunderstanding something or is this intended?

Although, there's another inconsistency between Edge and the other two: when maximizing the window, the resize event is triggered once on Edge and twice on Chrome and Firefox.
That shouldn't be much of a problem, but I'm curious about the reason behind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of requestAnimationFrame might be correct. What happens here is that browsers nowadays do already debounce the `resize` event to the screen refresh rate, [in accordance to the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:run-the-resize-steps).

This can be demonstrated by adding two event listeners, one debounced and one *nude*:

```js
addEventListener('resize', e => console.log('non-debounced'));
let active = null;
addEventListener('resize', e => {
  if(active) {
    console.log("cancelling");
    cancelAnimationFrame(active);
  }
  active = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    console.log('debounced');
    active = null;
  });
});
```

In both aforementioned browsers, the log will be

> non-debounced
>   debounced
>   non-debounced
>   debounced
>   ...

The fact that only a single "non-debounced" event handler fired in between two debunced ones proves that even the non-debounced version is actually debounced, by the browser.

So since these event are already debounced, your debouncer code is never reached.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear explanation. But what about Edge, then? Is it bad at debouncing or simply not doing it? And if so, should I keep using my code, for the sake of Edge?

Comment: All I can say is that they do fire the event at an higher rate than screen-refresh's one (might be once per event loop i.e no debounce at all). And yes, if all you do is some graphic reaction to this event, continue to debounce it through rAF, at least for older browsers (not all versions of other browsers did debounce it either). However if I may, your debouncer is quite memory consumptive, you'd be better using a simple boolean flag and call requestAnimationFrame only when it's false instead of cancelling + start again several times.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the remark about the memory consumption.

Comment: I can see it does work this way but do you know of any browsers that have actually documented that this is actually how it works?

Comment: @user779159 that's simply [per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:run-the-resize-steps)